# nltk.text() throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, corpus

I am currently using Python 3.4. When I invoke `nltk.text` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    nltk.text(tokens)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Evidently [`nltk.text`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html) is a *module*, not a *function*. Have you read [the `nltk` documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#module-nltk.text)? Why were you trying to call it in the first place?

Comment: If not, you should, [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html). Then you could probably figure out what you *actually* want to call to accomplish something.

Comment: Looking at the content of `nltk.text`, I think you may want [`nltk.text.Text`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text), which does take a `tokens` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe stated, `nltk.text` is a module and not a class or a function.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.text
<module 'nltk.text' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/text.py'>
```

There is however a class call `Text` in:

```
>>> nltk.text.Text
<class 'nltk.text.Text'>
```

However you can skip the namespace because it's "unherited" to the nltk superclass:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.Text
<class 'nltk.text.Text'>
```

It's a class object to read tokens (i.e. list of strings) and process them into "nltk-able" corpus. E.g.

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> string = "This is a small foobar corpus, with foobar sentence. Hello World, yes it's a foobar day"
>>> mycorpus = nltk.Text(word_tokenize(string))>>> mycorpus
<Text: This is a small foobar corpus , with...>
```

With the `Text` object you can perform several corpus analyses:

```
>> mycorpus
<Text: This is a small foobar corpus , with...>
>>> mycorpus.count('foobar')
3
>>> mycorpus.concordance('foobar')
Displaying 3 of 3 matches:
                                    foobar corpus , with foobar sentence . Hel
                                    foobar sentence . Hello World , yes it 's 
                                    foobar day
>>> mycorpus.index('foobar') # i.e. first instance of 'foobar'
4
>>> mycorpus.vocab()
FreqDist({'foobar': 3, ',': 2, 'a': 2, 'Hello': 1, 'small': 1, 'day': 1, 'is': 1, 'yes': 1, 'corpus': 1, 'This': 1, ...})
```

For more information on how `nltk.text.Text` works, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/text.py#L262 and

```
>>> dir(mycorpus)
['_CONTEXT_RE', '_COPY_TOKENS', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', '_concordance_index', '_context', '_vocab', 'collocations', 'common_contexts', 'concordance', 'count', 'dispersion_plot', 'findall', 'index', 'name', 'plot', 'readability', 'similar', 'tokens', 'unicode_repr', 'vocab']
```

Also, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/text.py#L575 and try:

```
>>> nltk.text.demo()
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback... went through the links..I tried to implement the context analysis in my case after incorporating the class ContextIndex in my code. But I got the following error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 1, in <module>
    ContextIndex(raw)
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 16, in __init__
    for i, w in enumerate(tokens))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 1700, in __init__
    for (cond, sample) in cond_samples:
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 16, in <genexpr>
    for i, w in enumerate(tokens))
TypeError: _default_context() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: I have used the tokens obtained after nltk.word_tokenize(raw) as argument for the ContextIndex class...Am I supposed to include the position of the tokens as well in the argument? Thanks in advance!